# AVAudioPlayer randomly not playing after setting currentTime to 0.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer instance (one of many) that is forced to restart play over and over again, usually before it ends. The sounds has about 1.3s and it is repeated about every 0.7s (when it crosses about half its duration).

The problem is that sometimes (maybe 5% of all cases) the sound does not play.

The file is a mono AAC (I tried two different short files with a similar effect).

The exact code looks like this:

```
- (void)restartPlay:(AVAudioPlayer *)player position:(CGPoint)p volume:(float)volume loops:(NSInteger)loops;
{
    NSString *filename = [self debug_resolveSoundName:player];

    DLogShort(@"\n[restartPlay...] in:   %@, %@, t:%f, vol:%f, pan:%f, loops:%li", filename, player.isPlaying?@"playing":@"not playing", player.currentTime, player.volume, player.pan, player.numberOfLoops);

    player.currentTime = 0.0;

    DLogShort(@"[restartPlay...] mid1:   %@, %@, t:%f, vol:%f, pan:%f, loops:%li", filename, player.isPlaying?@"playing":@"not playing", player.currentTime, player.volume, player.pan, player.numberOfLoops);

    [player play];

    DLogShort(@"[restartPlay...] mid2:   %@, %@, t:%f, vol:%f, pan:%f, loops:%li", filename, player.isPlaying?@"playing":@"not playing", player.currentTime, player.volume, player.pan, player.numberOfLoops);

    player.pan = [self getPan:p];
    player.volume = volume;
    player.numberOfLoops = loops;

    DLogShort(@"[restartPlay...] out:   %@, %@, t:%f, vol:%f, pan:%f, loops:%li \n", filename, player.isPlaying?@"playing":@"not playing", player.currentTime, player.volume, player.pan, player.numberOfLoops);
}
```

Output:

```
[restartPlay...] in:   audioFile1, playing, t:0.704104, vol:1.000000, pan:0.332738, loops:0
[restartPlay...] mid1:   audioFile1, not playing, t:0.000000, vol:1.000000, pan:0.332738, loops:0
[restartPlay...] mid2:   audioFile1, not playing, t:0.000000, vol:1.000000, pan:0.332738, loops:0
[restartPlay...] out:   audioFile1, not playing, t:0.000000, vol:1.000000, pan:0.311913, loops:0
```

What looks strange, is that the sound's property isPlaying is initially `YES` and after setting `currentTime` to zero (as I expect, the very beginning of the sample) its status `player.isPlaying` becomes `NO`. Then after calling `-play` it still does not play (`isPlaying` still `NO` and I do not hear it).

A next call to the same method on the same `AVAudioPlayer` instance fixes this (plays again).

Comment: Good intuition. It worked. Now all calls emit sound correctly. If you make this an answer I'd be happy to set it accepted. But I do not think this solution is documented and why it works? Some issues with asynchronous playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to stop or pause, then change the current time, then play.